# android layout deisgn : I want to create a layout with dynamic textbox

Tags: android

I am new to android app development.I want to create a app in which user need to submit his complaint on product.When user click add button in the page. three text box should be shown as show below

1. Incident name ( search widget)
2. description
3. date and time

Similarly user can add "n" number of incidents and submit his query.

Please let me know how to achieve . if there is any example or tutorial Please point me to that.

Comment: create textbox programatically and save its id in array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just you placed below code when user clicked button...

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout2);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Dynamic TextView" + i);
    tv.setId(i + 5);
    ll.addView(tv);
}

It will generate textboxs dynamically.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for dialogs. They are an elegant way of not taking user away to another screen but ask for lightweight feedback on whatever you want on the same screen itself.

Here's the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure people will be adding a log of such incidents, you can have a look at `recyclerView` which is not too easy for total newbies but ain't that difficult either. You can fill up user's data and add it to the `recyclerView` to make it appear like a list of incidents about one topic.

[RecyclerView documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) 
[RecyclerView demo](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=recyclerview%20demo)

Happy learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Context context = this;


LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);   
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        final EditText yourEditText =(EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id. yourEditText);

            alertDialogBuilder
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Button1",
                              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) { 

         }



                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("Button2",
                                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {


                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                  });


        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();




                                alertDialog.show();
```

Now create "yourlayout" with all your EditText, this will pop up as a dialog. Don't forget promptsView. before findViewById

```
final EditText yourEditText =(EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id. yourEditText);
```